# Pyspark: how to reference a column by a name that is itself a data point

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Background: I'm new to Spark and distributed computing in general so this is a learning exercise rather than a real-life one. The challenge is to do solve the problem without a UDF.

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
+------+------+----+--------+---------+----------+
|f_name|s_name|year|district|check_col|true_value|
+------+------+----+--------+---------+----------+
|  John| Smith|1981|     SW8|   s_name|     Smith|
|  Jane| Jones|1980|     L15|   s_name|     Smith|
|  John| Smith|1981|     SW8|     year|      1980|
|  Jane| Jones|1980|     L15|     year|      1980|
+------+------+----+--------+---------+----------+
```

I want to check whether the value of the column named in `check_col` is equal to the `true_value`. Specifically, I'll add a new boolean column whose the value on a row is True if (and only if!) the column named in check_col has the value specified in true_value.

In this example, the value for the first row would be True because check_col = "s_name" and the value of the s_name column on that row is "Smith", which is equal to the value in "true_value".

I'd hoped the following would work but it doesn't:

```
df = df.withColumn(
  "Check",
  df[df["check_col"]] == df["true_value"]
)
```

I suspect it would be a good idea to try joining the table to itself but I can't see my way to a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Lookup using `map` type

```
from itertools import chain

cols = ['f_name', 's_name', 'year', 'district']

# Mapping (k, V) where K is column name and V is correponding value
mapping = F.create_map(*chain(*[(F.lit(c), F.col(c)) for c in cols]))

# lookup the check_col in mapping
df = df.withColumn('check', mapping[F.col('check_col')] == F.col('true_value'))
```

#### Result

```
+------+------+----+--------+---------+----------+-----+
|f_name|s_name|year|district|check_col|true_value|check|
+------+------+----+--------+---------+----------+-----+
|  John| Smith|1981|     SW8|   s_name|     Smith| true|
|  Jane| Jones|1980|     L15|   s_name|     Smith|false|
|  John| Smith|1981|     SW8|     year|      1980|false|
|  Jane| Jones|1980|     L15|     year|      1980| true|
+------+------+----+--------+---------+----------+-----+
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! Looks like map() is going to be very useful...